# Flow Control with UARTs

Tags: linux, serial-port, microcontroller, uart

Consider that I want to connect two microcontrollers (one master running Linux, one slave). Consider that the master asks the slave to send some chunk of data. For the sake of argument, this chunk of data is 16 KB large.

To the best of by knowledge, UARTs do not offer flow control in both directions. In my case, the master only has 4 UART pins: TX, RX, RTS, and CTS. As far as I know, RTS/CTS protect the slave's receive buffer from overflowing. However, in the above example, the receive buffer of the master may actually overflow. The reason is that Linux kernel does seem to use a receive buffer of around 4095 bytes. If the userspace application doesn't read the data fast enough, then the buffer simply overflows. The userspace application may be stalling on disk or network I/O for example.

Software flow control using special in-band escape sequences seems to be flawed as well. Basically, the classic XON/XOFF software flow control requires, that the master sends some XOFF control character before its receive buffer overflows. Doing that in the userspace application seems wrong, as the userspace application cannot guarantee to send XOFF in time. So unless it's part of the Linux kernel drivers, it won't work reliably. However, I cannot find any information about whether (and if so when) the kernel driver would send an XOFF control character. Also, the slave will take some time to react the incoming XOFF. How fast must the slave react? If the Linux kernel driver sends the XOFF, what does it assume about the slave?

Right now, I fancy some kind of flow control along the lines of what TCP does: as the master reads data, it sends acknowledgements to the slave. Every N bytes the master has read, it will send an Ack to the slave. That tells the slave, that N more bytes are now available in the receive buffer of the master. If the slave has an estimate of the master's initial receive buffer size, that should work well. That would of course require to ask the Linux kernel for the total size of the receive buffer.

This leads me to the following series of questions:

1. How do people actually implement flow control in both directions using UARTs?
2. How can I get the receive buffer size from the kernel? APIs like pyserial dont seem to offer anything. (The 4095 I gave above is the result of my own experiments and has been confirmed by looking at the kernel source)
3. Can the kernel's receive buffer be enlarged by the userspace application? Again, APIs like pyserial don't offer anything and the kernel source didn't look like the size of the buffer was adjustable.
4. Besides USB (which has flow control), what do people use as an alternative to UARTs to avoid these issues?

**Update**: Many sources still state, that the master sets RTS (=request to send) when it wants to send data to the slave. The slave then acknowledges the request by setting CTS (=clear to send). This allows flow control in one direction only. However, the [English Wikipedia on RS-232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) states, that the RTS line was redefined to something more appropriately called RTR (ready to receive) in the 1980s. RTR/CTS allows flow control in both directions.

Comment: *"To the best of by knowledge, RS232 does not offer flow control in both directions."* -- Your knowledge is flawed.  *"XOFF escape sequence"* -- XON/XOFF *flow control* is a distinct concept from *escape sequences*.

Comment: are you talking about microcontrollers or something running linux?

Comment: why would you design your driver to match something that allows you to overflow?  make a better driver.

Comment: xon/xoff is not part of RS232 it is in band with the protocol riding at the layer above the uart.  uarts dont necessarily support RTS/CTS automatically (in hardware, despite calling it hardware flow control it wasnt), some do many of the ones in PCs did not, so I would expect them to certainly not support XON/XOFF themselves so you end up losing data rather than getting the in band XOFF out.  And of course you then couldnt use those bit patterns for data making your transmission that much less effiicent.

Comment: usb uses fewer signals than uart, and is a one directional protocol, master slave, you could easily implement a master slave yourself but that just means one side is at the mercy of the other and cannot freely move info at the speed it wants.  that is yet another already solved solution (was solved before usb used it).

Comment: I have updated my questions to address the wrong terminology. Also, I found out about the difference between RTS/CTS and RTR/CTS. The former is flow control in one direction, while the latter is flow control in both directions. It seems RTR/CTS is often falsely called RTS/CTS.

Comment: You cross over the RTS/CTS signals just as you do RxD/TxD and this does give you flow control in both directions, assuming both UARTs support this in hardware.

Comment: @old_timer: XMODEM for example sends packets of 128bytes. The receive buffer on Linux must be larger than 128 bytes - which it is. ZMODEM on the other hand uses a sliding window. The window must not be larger than 4KB, or the receive buffer on the Linux size could overflow if userspace stalls. That is certainly something that should be avoided. So it all comes down to how to determine the receive buffer size of a tty on Linux. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: In my experience all solutions which rely on some OS supported flow control _for the serial port_ are doomed because you will always run into some machine where either the different layer drivers don't harmonize or are plainly buggy. RS232 is such a dark,dusty and abandoned corner in todays technology stack that not much quality assurance goes into it. We always rolled our own protocols on top of the assumed lossy, Rx/Tx-only, 8-bit  interface.

Answer (score 2):

Only old equipment such as modems use hardware flow control in the way you describe it, because they tend to have very fixed master/slave relationships.

UARTs on microcontrollers use the following configuration:

[image]

I think your misunderstanding stems from the fact that you assume that there is only one RTS/CTS pair in modern equipment, when in fact there are two -- one for each party.

Much like the TX/RX pair of lines, RTS/CTS need to be crossed over when connected, see for instance [SiLabs AN0059](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoVjd.png) for a more in-depth description. That's where the picture is taken from. They also briefly describe "legacy hardware flow control".

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoVjd.png): https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/AN0059.pdf Silicon Laboratories AN0059

Comment: Have you ever read the description of the RTS line on Wikipedia, for example? It described the old, outdated meaning which was that the master is ready to send data - not that the master is ready to receive data. That has changed. However, many pages on the web seem to be outdated and describe the old meaning of the RTS line. As I stated in my post, the new usage of the RTS line is also knows as RTR (ready to receive).